# Render or Use DocumentFragment in a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a requirement in my React-based application to render dynamic forms. The form definitions are stored as JSON documents and I already have a JS library that parses the definitions and returns a DocumentFragment. This library is used in other non-React applications as well so I cannot change it.

To avoid re-writing the entire logic in my React application to parse the definitions and render the forms, I want to use the existing library.

My question is, what would be the best way to render the DocumentFragment in a React component?

Here is my DocumentFragment if I just output it to the console in my render() method.

```
#document-fragment
    <fieldset id="metadata-form-908272" class="metadata-form-rendition hide-pages">
      <div class="page-header-row">
        <div class="page-header-cell">
          <span>[Un-named page]</span>
          <button class="page-header-button button icon">
            <span class="icon icon-arrow-up-11"></span></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="page-area" id="metadata-form-page-001-area">
        <div class="question-row">
          <div class="question-label-cell mandatory">I have read and understood my obligations:</div>
          <div class="question-input-cell">
            <div class="validation-message"></div>
            <label><input type="radio" value="Yes" name="metadata-form-908272-question-1">
              <span>Yes</span></label>
            <label><input type="radio" value="No" name="metadata-form-908272-question-1">
              <span>No</span></label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="question-row">
          <div class="question-label-cell">Please state all sources for the information provided:</div>
          <div class="question-input-cell">
            <div class="validation-message"></div>
            <div class="formatted-editor">
              <div class="editor-area" contenteditable="true">
                <p>​</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: __DocumentFragment__  here is result of utilizing `document.createDocumentFragment();`?

Comment: Yes, it is. The external library uses document.createDocumentFragment() to create the DocumentFragment. In my React component, I call theExternalLibrary.getFormFragment({some_data}). This call returns me the DocumentFragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update: Security Alert!**

Thanks for reminding from @JaredSmith in comment, the method provided here
really has security issue. It's not proper to apply it if the library is not from your internal.

To learn more about the issue, you could look into the link of dangerouslysetinnerhtml I referred below.

---

Here is indeed a tricky way to achieve your goal. By the information you provided in comment:

> ... I call theExternalLibrary.getFormFragment({some_data}) ...

cause that `DocumentFragments` only in memory, maybe as you know, we need to append the fragment to a real DOM element first, so let's just create a root element for appending:

```
let rootElement = document.createElement("div");
let frag = theExternalLibrary.getFormFragment({some_data});
rootElement.appendChild(frag);
```

Now we have a pure JavaScript elements DOM tree here. In order to convert it to React elements, here is the way which involves a method that react provides: [dangerouslysetinnerhtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)
You could see that this method is not encouraged to use by its scary name.

```
render() {
  let rootElement = document.createElement("div");
  let frag = theExternalLibrary.getFormFragment({some_data});
  rootElement.appendChild(frag);
  // rootElement.innerHTML is in string type.
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: rootElement.innerHTML }} />;
}
```

Live example:

[image: Edit DocumentFragment]

Comment: The dangerous part of `innerHTML` is that it can lead to a script injection attack, which is true whether you use react or not.

Comment: @JaredSmith, thank you for your additional explanation. So more accurately is that it already has secure issue when I utilize `rootElement.innerHTML` in my answer.

Comment: Yes that's right... I would be *very* reluctant to assign data I got from a third party to `innerHTML`...

Comment: @JaredSmith, I agree with you. But in this case it seems like have no other ways except rewriting the feature it needs ... or maybe it would be safer to check if the string has script or any listener XD? But if so, we earn another nuisance.

Comment: Thanks @Carr, I can trust the generated HTML as it’s our own library used purely to parse JSON array and and generate form HTML. The generated HTML will not have scripts.

Comment: @Carr, would you have some thought on this approach? It uses React.createRef from React 16.3 and appends formFragment using refInstance.current.appendChild(). https://codesandbox.io/s/k9k04vnrk3

Comment: @Avi, I think that is better than what I've provided, thanks, I've learned.

Comment: @Avi, Maybe you should override my answer by the method you found, that is elegant.

Comment: @Carr It seems both approaches have pros and cons. It we use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, React does not care about the DOM as it's coming from another source. This helps performance. However, this is an issue in my case as I want to read the data entered by the user in the form. With appending fragment to the node provided by ref, it still has the same effect but I'm able to read the form data. One issue in this case is if the component re-renders, the form data being entered by the user will be overwritten. Need to implement the `componentDidUpdate` carefully.

Comment: This also loses state stored in <input type='file"> and similar nodes that store state in an opaque way.

Answer (score 1):

I took a crack at this myself, as DOMPurify and the upcoming Sanitiser API work best when returning DocumentFragments:

```js
function getDocumentFragment(text) {
  const f = document.createDocumentFragment();
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = text;
  f.appendChild(p);
  return f;
}

class FragmentRenderer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.setRef = this.setRef.bind(this);
  }

  setRef(ref) {
    this.ref = ref;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.appendFragment();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.text != this.props.text) {
      this.appendFragment();
    }
  }

  appendFragment() {
    if (!this.ref) {
      return;
    }
    while (this.ref.firstChild) {
      this.ref.removeChild(this.ref.firstChild);
    }
    this.ref.appendChild(getDocumentFragment(this.props.text));
  }

  render() {
    return React.createElement("div", {
      ref: this.setRef
    });
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(FragmentRenderer, {
  text: "Just like this"
}), document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

So now you're not casting to a string and using dangerouslySetInnerHTML, which can in extreme cases lead to the elements you write being different to the elements in the original fragment, due to parsing issues. However, you do still need to trust whereever this fragment came from - it *cannot* come from a user-controlled source. DOMPurify or the Sanitizer API will be your best friends here.